# Creating divs for each data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, json

I trying to create divs for each data,
To put it mildly, what I'm trying to do is,
When I post, it will be added to the database
The data I add on the post list page will be created in a different divde separate from other data

My Html

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/postList.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div class="postsMain">
 </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/listPost.js"></script>
```

Connected JS file

```js
$(function () {
  $.getJSON("/admin/getposts", function (data) {
    $(".postsMain").empty();
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
      console.log("Data girdi") 
      var alt = $("<div>", {
        class: "postsAlt"
      }).appendTo(".postsMain");
      $("<p>").html(item.title).appendTo(alt);
      console.log('Başarıyla data çekildi'); 
    });
  });
});
```

Data's i get from JS file

```
[
    { "title": "Https test ", "content": "https://endorfintr.tk", "sharer": "EndorfinTR" },
    { "title": "a", "content": "ÇAYLARRRRR", "sharer": "DataBaseTester", "editer": "EndorfinTR" },
    {
        "title": "Bakım sürecinin %75i bitti! ",
        "content": "Bakım sürecinin %75inden fazlasına girmis bulunmaktayız, bu süreçte adminleri ve siteyi kökten etkileyecek bir sürü ekleme yapıldı. Örneğin Post ekleme, post silme benzeri şeyler eklendi. /n Bakım sürecinin bitiminde görüşmek üzere ",
        "sharer": "EndorfinTR",
        "editer": "EndorfinTR"
    },
    { "title": "Blog Websitesine Kısa Bir Ara", "content": "Merhabalar ben EndorfinTR, websiteye biraz ara vereceğim. Çünkü hostumuzda bir kaç arıza çıktı.", "sharer": "EndorfinTR" },
    { "title": "Rus - Ukrayna savaşı Müzakereleri", "content": "Rus - Ukrayna savaşı tarafları Belarus sınırında müzakere yapacak, sonuçlar için beklemeyi unutmayın!", "sharer": "ThesseliaTR" },
    { "title": "Merhabaaa", "content": "Selam", "sharer": "ThesseliaTR", "date": "09 Mart Çarşamba 2022, 21:00" }
]
```

```css
.postsAlt {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 25px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0,0.2);
  background-color: #808080;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
} 

.postsAlt p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 1;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Have you already used angular?

Comment: What does this have to do with Angular @Pieterjan?

Comment: This line `$("<p>").html(item.title).appendTo(alt);` appends the item title to the `alt` element. You just need to do that for `content`, `sharer`, and `editor` etc.

Comment: (Because mvvm frameworks make it easier to mainain the code)

Comment: Yes, maintaining the code *might be a little easier*. AFTER you managed to install Angular and have gone through all the necessary training to know how to build apps with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little snippet demonstrating how you could change the `.each()` part in your code:

```js
const da=[{ "title": "Https test ", "content": "https://endorfintr.tk", "sharer": "EndorfinTR" },
{ "title": "a", "content": "ÇAYLARRRRR", "sharer": "DataBaseTester", "editer": "EndorfinTR" },
{
    "title": "Bakım sürecinin %75i bitti! ",
    "content": "Bakım sürecinin %75inden fazlasına girmis bulunmaktayız, bu süreçte adminleri ve siteyi kökten etkileyecek bir sürü ekleme yapıldı. Örneğin Post ekleme, post silme benzeri şeyler eklendi. /n Bakım sürecinin bitiminde görüşmek üzere ",
    "sharer": "EndorfinTR",
    "editer": "EndorfinTR"
},
 { "title": "Blog Websitesine Kısa Bir Ara", "content": "Merhabalar ben EndorfinTR, websiteye biraz ara vereceğim. Çünkü hostumuzda bir kaç arıza çıktı.", "sharer": "EndorfinTR" },
 { "title": "Rus - Ukrayna savaşı Müzakereleri", "content": "Rus - Ukrayna savaşı tarafları Belarus sınırında müzakere yapacak, sonuçlar için beklemeyi unutmayın!", "sharer": "ThesseliaTR" },
 { "title": "Merhabaaa", "content": "Selam", "sharer": "ThesseliaTR", "date": "09 Mart Çarşamba 2022, 21:00" }];

console.log("Data girdi")
$.each(da, function (i, item) {    $(".postsMain").append(`<div class="postsAlt">
<h3>${item.title}</h3><p>${item.content}</p>
<p>Shared by: ${item.sharer}</p><p>Edited by: ${item.editer}</p></div>`); 
});
console.log('Başarıyla data çekildi');
```

```css
.xpostsAlt {border:1px solid grey; margin:10px 0; padding:0 10px}
.postsAlt {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 25px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0,0.2);
  background-color: #808080;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
} 

.postsAlt p {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="postsMain"></div>
```

Comment: It's the same, but I think there's only one when the divs are intertwined, should I send the CSS?

Comment: Could you clarify your comment? I added some CSS to my answer to visualise that each answer in the `da` array  will be shown in its own `<div class="postsAlt>`.

Comment: May not be set up in CSS, should I send CSS?

Comment: Whatever helps to clarify matters ... ;-)

Comment: Okay, I added css.

Comment: Well, yes, your CSS uses `absolute` positioning for all your `.postsAlt` divs. That means that they will all be superimposed at exactly the same position. You need to remove the `position: absolute` attribute from your CSS and maybe adjust a few other things there if you want the posts to appear beneath each other.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it's worked out very well for me, but can I ask you one more question? I've centered the divs, but they're all adjacent. How can we separate them all a little bit?

Comment: Maybe you can add some `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to them? My `margin: 10px 0` already provides for  10px margins at top and bottom and 0px margins at left and right.

Comment: Thanks, my question ends here. Thanks for your help. ❤️